# Angular 6 custom element interaction with parent DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, custom-element

I am using [angular element](https://angular.io/guide/elements) for javascript error reporting.
I am following this [tutorial](https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-custom-error-handling-with-angular-e0d612d67575?__s=vust4uavq4aoopyszqnr) for error handling and reporting in the angular application. This code is working in angular application but I want to reuse it outside the angular application. So I have packed this code in an angular element and used as a custom element in a non-angular application. But it doesn't work.

I think angular elements don't have the access to the scope of the page. 
But I am not sure what is the problem here, I just want to know this is possible or not, If yes what mistake I am doing.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To access angular elements or component, you can go through this.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

It allow you to access and manupulate element of another component.

If you are trying to access method from outside the source. you should go through ngZone

https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone